# How to Replace specific part using regex python

Tags: python, regex

**views.py**

```
combineKeyword =""myKeyword", "Auto", "st3-throttling-cdb", "functional""
template_desc2 = "@Test(groups = { "Code-planned", "Code-not automated", "Code-st3reporter" }
import re
re.sub(r' @Test\(groups\s*=\s*\{([^\}]+)',combineKeyword,template_desc2)
```

Here i want to replace "Code-planned", "Code-not automated", "Code-st3reporter" these keyword and put `combineKeyword` at there

Comment: Show clearly what is your sample input and what is your expected output. Also add the regex you have so far, which you need help to complete.

Comment: You've got some syntax errors in that code. Hint: If you use `"` to signify a string, that string can't contain unescaped `"` values.

Comment: input is combineKeyword string which i want to replace with "Code-planned", "Code-not automated", "Code-st3reporter"  these words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has syntax errors, I am presuming the string is wrapped in  single quotes `''` and the inner strings are like `"Code-planned"`

```
s = '@Test(groups = { "Code-planned", "Code-not automated", "Code-st3reporter" ,"different"}'

print  re.sub('Code-[^"]*',"my new string",s )

@Test(groups = { "my new string", "my new string", "my new string" ,"different"}
```

If you want to replace all the strings whether they start with Code- or not :

```
s = '@Test(groups = { "Code-planned", "Code-not automated", "Code-st3reporter" ,"different"}'

print re.sub(r'\"(.*?)\"','"my new string"',s)

@Test(groups = { "my new string", "my new string", "my new string" ,"my new string"}
```